# The correct way to interpret aggregated-level correlation

Tags: correlation, aggregation

One keeps seeing comments from the statisticians that say researchers interpret the correlations based on aggregated data falsely. This made me wonder, well how does one correctly interpret it then?

To put things into context, I am working with a small sample size data wishing to explore the associations between cognition (1 variable) and outcome performance (2 variable). I am, however, interesting to see how these relationships differ between two experience levels. For that reason, I aggregated both variables by an average number of practice hours (4 categories) per subject. I then correlated these aggregated variables and found they confirm the individual-level correlations with the difference that the strengths of the relationship changed.

Now I'm wondering if someone from the statistical community can advise this seemingly naive researcher on how to best interpret these correlations. Does one only say the trend shows a positive trend between variable 1 and variable 2 when considering practice hours or can more specific inferences be made?

Appreciate any expert advice!